# Android make HTTP request and wait for the server

Tags: android, http, client-server

A client Android device requests a service hosted in the PC server, but the server cannot reply right away. This is because the server first waits a while for other clients' requests and then solves an optimization problem over all requests recently received, and then sends the result to all clients.

I wonder how I can achieve this by calling Android API, and what I need (language, programming framework like Node.js) at the server side. Thanks.

Comment: This is a question that can only be answered by subjective opinion and as such will likely be closed. That said, consider looking into Node.js as a server and Socket.io to send async messages to connected clients. It sounds like you want an async push service and these technologies will do exactly that.

Comment: Thank you trnelson. I made some edits to make it clearer. I work on a paper deadline, so do you think Node.js is cheap (in terms of time and complexity) to deal with?

Comment: That's really hard to answer. Asking clients to wait for a response is handled one of two ways: a socket/async service where server pushes messages to clients, or client polling (or long polling) where client periodically asks server for response and either waits for it, or it gets nothing and continues to try silently. The latter can be done in any technology, but node/socket.io handle all cases.

Comment: Node and socket.io are very nice tools. I'm new to them but so far easy to set up and use. That said, both use JavaScript (client and server) so that simplifies a bit, but it doesn't sound like you have a lot of JavaScript experience either. If C++ is more your bag, you may be able to find a simple server SDK in C++ to use, but would still need to write client logic.

Comment: Thank you trnelson. To be consistent with Android, I think maybe a httppost waiting for the results from the server is the easiest way to do the trick, which is absolutely not an elegant way for modern scalable client/server solution. Do you think so?

Comment: It should honestly be just fine. You may already, but just make sure you understand the difference between *polling* and *long polling*, the latter of which may or may not be possible without something like Socket.io (but it may be!) As long as your server can handle the requests there's no problem going this route, especially if it's in your realm of understanding. Standard to best case it works perfectly. Worst case you refactor slightly. For personal development, do consider looking into async web at some point. It's fascinating. :)

Comment: It turns out that I choose Play for the simplicity. Thanks trnelson, your replies were very helpful.